# Connect to Informix without an entry in /etc/services (matching sqlhosts)

Tags: informix

I have Informix databases running in Docker containers. They have unpredictable published port numbers.

I am trying to connect from outside the container. Informix seems to want an entry in the sqlhosts file. I can create an ad hoc `/tmp/sqlhosts.xxx` containing

```
 mydbservername onsoctcp <container ip address> <servicename>
```

and use it with

```
INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/tmp/sqlhosts.xxx /my.program
```

and `my.program` connects to `dbname@mydbservername`, I  have verified this temporary sqlhosts file *is* being read and the `mydbservername` *is* being discovered.

The error is

```
Cannot locate <servicename> service in /etc/services.
```

So far, so hacky, but it seems to work apart from the `<servicename>` part. In static environments, this would match an entry in `/etc/services` but I don't have write privileges for that file (and in any case, the dynamic port numbers would make it messy).

Ideally I would be able to connect to the database without going through a sqlhosts file at all -- the IP address and port number are known when I execute`my.program` -- but there is a layer I don't control between `my.program` and the database connection itself: I can only control the `dbname@server` string, the userspace filesystem, and the environment variables.

How can I connect to an Informix database which manifests with an unpredictable IP/port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a port number instead of a service name in the `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` file.  I do that most of the time.  For example, one `sqlhosts` file I currently use on a machine `lxdev04` contains:

```
# lxdev04_23 on lxdev04 added 2019-04-24 14:59:32
lxdev04_23      olsoctcp  lxdev04  10040
lxdev04_23_tcp  olsoctcp  lxdev04  10041
lxdev04_23_shm  olipcshm  lxdev04  lxdev04_23
lxdev04_23_str  olipcstr  lxdev04  lxdev04_23
lxdev04_23_ssl  olsocssl  lxdev04  10042
lxdev04_23_enc  olsoctcp  lxdev04  10043         csm=(lxdev04_23_enc)
lxdev04_23_pwd  olsoctcp  lxdev04  10044         csm=(lxdev04_23_pwd)
```

The shared memory and stream connections use a name (but those aren't in `/etc/services` anyway), but the rest use just a port number.  I name my Informix servers with the machine name (`lxdev04`) and a 2-digit prime number, which is also the server number, plus suffixes for different connection types.

The advantage of a service name (which is simply a way to map between a name string and a port number) is that it can be used across machines if you use an appropriate service (NIS+, etc), and they can be changed if necessary.  It is harder to mess with numbers.